# add elements multiple values in XDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, junit

I want to add a section with tag name called properties, and have one item value called property with multiple value, like node name, value

org xml file is like this

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        blah blah
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

After add, i want it show like this

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <properties>
        <property name="name" "value"="desirevalue"/>
        </properties>
        blah blah
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

The code that i wrote has some problems, it actually create two line of property, but i want them as one line. How should i update my code? Also seems last two line has problems. i get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileOfReportInXML);
XElement root= new XElement("properties");
root.Add(new XElement("property", "name= node"));
root.Add(new XElement("property","value=desirevalue"));
doc.Element("testsuite").Add(root);
doc.Save(fileOfReportInXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
//Load XML file
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileOfReportInXML);
```

**Edit: Add element to the first element of your xdocument**

```
doc.Root.Elements("testsuite").First().Add(new XElement("properties", new XElement("property", new XAttribute("name", "name"), new XAttribute("value", "desirevalue"))));
```

**if you want to add new elements to all your testsuite elements:**

```
foreach (var element in doc.Root.Elements("testsuite"))
{
     //Skip adding element if element already exists
     if (element.HasElements && element.Element("properties") != null) continue;

     element.Add(new XElement("properties", new XElement("property", new XAttribute("name", "name"), new XAttribute("value", "desirevalue"))));
}
```

Save the XML document

```
//Save XML file
doc.Save(fileOfReportInXML);
```

Comment: I get an error showing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." with your solution

Comment: And if i change that to doc.Element("testsuites").Add(new XElement("properties", new XElement("property", new XAttribute("name", "name"), new XAttribute("value", "desirevalue")))); then it is fine for compile, but that is not what i want. What is the difference between doc.Element("testsuites") and doc.Element("testsuite")